# cmake, keeping link flags of internal libs

Tags: gcc, cmake, lto

In src/foo I create lib foo linked with -lwhatever

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(foo -lwhatever)
```

In src/bar I use foo

```
add_executable (bar bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

Might be thanks to LTO, but I need to add -lwhatever to target_link_libraries of bar otherwise I have missing symbols at compile time.

```
target_link_libraries(bar foo -lwhatever)
```

Can't it be done transparently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of CMake 3.0, CMake is missing the `INTERFACE_LINK_FLAGS` target property which would make this possible.

The problem here is really that using `target_link_libraries` to specify linker flags was not the smartest design decision in the first place. A separate command in the spirit of `target_compile_options` would have been desirable.

I consider this an oversight in CMake. If you have a relevant use case, you might be able to argue for the inclusion of a `target_link_flags` command in a future CMake version. Feel free to contact the developer's mailing list if this is a major concern for you.

An alternative for now would be to use the [`LINK_FLAGS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS.html) target property of `foo` to specify the link flags. You can then also inspect that property at the point where you specify `bar` to avoid having to hardcode the options twice, effectively turning it into an `INTERFACE_*` property manually. But that's about as good as it gets.